# Is there have analog for HtmlTableRow in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm porting app from .NET to .NET Core and can't find analog for HtmlTableRow class

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HtmlTableRow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: `using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` is not there?

Comment: Sorry - but: error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: And System.Web exists only in .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of WebForms, which is not part of .NET Standard, and will never be available on .NET Core. You can't easily port a WebForms application to .NET Core. You'd have to change it into an ASP.NET MVC application first, and that won't be trivial.